# nested quantifiers clarification

Tags: logic

If I let $F(x, y)$ be "$x$ can see $y$" be the correct syntax for "Everyone can see John" equate to $$\forall x(\exists \mbox{John} \enspace F(x,\mbox{John}))$$
and/or
$$\forall x(\exists y \enspace F(x, y))$$, how would that differ from "Everyone can see someone"?

Comment: For the first statement, if $John$ is a particular element of the set (as the existential sign would seem to imply) there is no need to say $\exists John$, you can just write $\forall x~F(x,John)$. In that case, you could construe your first statement as being the same as your second ("$John$ is a variable name like $y$) and both meaning "Everyone can see someone."

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is badly formed because $\exists$ must be followed by a variable, and **John** is a constant, not a variable.  Suggest you think about it in three steps:

(1) can you write in symbols "Jane can see John"?

(2) can you write "$x$ can see John", where $x$ is an unspecified person?

(3) can you write "everyone can see John"?

Good luck!